# Passing object implementations over file/network instead of data alone

Tags: java, serialization

I was experimenting on command pattern and one use of it in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Uses) goes like this:

> Networking
>
> It is possible to send whole command objects across the network to be executed on the other machines, for example player actions in computer games.

I assume here sending objects means sending data within the fields of the object, right? And not the code within the `execute()` method?

I was experimenting through serialization & found a behaviour I couldn't explain. Here's the program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Commands"))) {
            Command command = () -> {
                System.out.println("MUHAHA!");
            };
            outputStream.writeObject(command);
        }
        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Commands"))) {
            Command command = (Command) inputStream.readObject();
            command.execute();
        }
    }
}

interface Command extends Serializable {
    void execute();
}
```

Upon execution, I get the string `MUHAHA!`. So, the implementation of the `execute()` method is being saved in the file. However, if I comment out the first `try{}` block & then execute, it fails. The `Commands` file remains from the previous execution, but it fails to read & parse.

I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at random.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: random.Test.$deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

The `NoSuchMethodException` makes some sense to me, but why didn't it come the first time? Is it storing the first class created through lambda in some cache (or the Metaspace)?

In the end, is it possible to send an implementation across? I was hoping in the other end the code of the `execute` method will be written into some dynamically created `Command` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not storing the implementation in the file. To show that, separate your code into two classes: one that serializes  and one that deserializes, *and* execute them in different environments where neither has the .class files of the other.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I checked the `Commands` file & I think it's pointing to the lambda function within the first `try{}` block. I confused myself by using the lambda feature. Assumed it'll go out of scope & not exist after `}`. So the implementing class exists & it rightly instantiated that same one & stored into the 2nd command. Thanks!